# NameError: name 'load_modules' is not defined when using 'exec' for compile the macros in python

Tags: python, module, compilation

my python_scripts are in C:/NB/DATA/CST/CST_13/scripts and now I want compile and use them in python shell.

for that I am using following code.

```
exec(open('C:/NB/DATA/CST/CST_13/scripts/load_modules.py').read())
load_modules()
```

The above syntax working fine when I am running manually.

If i used that in another macro it throws the following error for me:

```
NameError: name 'load_modules' is not defined
```

Kindly anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try : `exec(open('C:\\NB\\DATA\\CST\\CST_13\\scripts\\load_modules.py').read())`

Comment: both are same know. But I tried that it throws  same error.

Answer (score 0):

After my investigation on it i found one solution for it, i.e we have to pass globals() parameter to the exec function.

```
exec(open('C:/NB/DATA/CST/CST_13/scripts/load_modules.py').read(),globals())
```